# Weights of nn.ModuleList() are adjusted even if no forward propagation was applied

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to use nn.ModuleList() to conduct some multitask learning, but the weights of all list elements (i.e. tasks) are adjusted when they were trained before. The following code (based on this [notebook](https://github.com/hosseinshn/Basic-Multi-task-Learning/blob/master/MTL-Pytorch.ipynb)) creates a neural network object called `MTL`.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import os
from torch.autograd import Variable
import math
import sklearn.preprocessing as sk
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import random

#creating training data
seed = 42
random.seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

N = 10000
M = 100
c = 0.5
p = 0.9
k = np.random.randn(M)
u1 = np.random.randn(M)
u1 -= u1.dot(k) * k / np.linalg.norm(k)**2
u1 /= np.linalg.norm(u1) 
k /= np.linalg.norm(k) 
u2 = k
w1 = c*u1
w2 = c*(p*u1+np.sqrt((1-p**2))*u2)
X = np.random.normal(0, 1, (N, M))
eps1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.01)
eps2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.01)
Y1 = np.matmul(X, w1) + np.sin(np.matmul(X, w1))+eps1
Y2 = np.matmul(X, w2) + np.sin(np.matmul(X, w2))+eps2
split = list(np.random.permutation(N))

X_train = X[split[0:8000],:]
Y1_train = Y1[split[0:8000]]
Y2_train = Y2[split[0:8000]]
X_valid = X[8000:9000,:]
Y1_valid = Y1[8000:9000]
Y2_valid = Y2[8000:9000]
X_test = X[9000:10000,:]
Y1_test = Y1[9000:10000]
Y2_test = Y2[9000:10000]

X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train)
X_train = X_train.float()
Y1_train = torch.tensor(Y1_train)
Y1_train = Y1_train.float()
Y2_train = torch.tensor(Y2_train)
Y2_train = Y2_train.float()

X_valid = torch.from_numpy(X_valid)
X_valid = X_valid.float()
Y1_valid = torch.tensor(Y1_valid)
Y1_valid = Y1_valid.float()
Y2_valid = torch.tensor(Y2_valid)
Y2_valid = Y2_valid.float()

X_test = torch.from_numpy(X_test)
X_test = X_test.float()
Y1_test = torch.tensor(Y1_test)
Y1_test = Y1_test.float()
Y2_test = torch.tensor(Y2_test)
Y2_test = Y2_test.float()

input_size, feature_size = X.shape

LR = 0.001
epoch = 50
mb_size = 100

#the network
class MTLnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MTLnet, self).__init__()

        self.sharedlayer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(feature_size, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout()
        )

        output = ['tower1', 'tower2']
        self.scoring_list = nn.ModuleList()

        for task, lab in enumerate(output):      
            tower = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(64, 32),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout(),
                nn.Linear(32, 16),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout(),
                nn.Linear(16, 1)
            )
            self.scoring_list.append(tower)

    def forward(self, x, task_id):
        h_shared = self.sharedlayer(x)
        logits = self.scoring_list[task_id](h_shared)

        return logits

def random_mini_batches(XE, R1E, R2E, mini_batch_size = 3, seed = 42): 
    # Creating the mini-batches
    np.random.seed(seed)            
    m = XE.shape[0]                  
    mini_batches = []
    permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
    shuffled_XE = XE[permutation,:]
    shuffled_X1R = R1E[permutation]
    shuffled_X2R = R2E[permutation]
    num_complete_minibatches = math.floor(m/mini_batch_size)
    for k in range(0, int(num_complete_minibatches)):
        mini_batch_XE = shuffled_XE[k * mini_batch_size : (k+1) * mini_batch_size, :]
        mini_batch_X1R = shuffled_X1R[k * mini_batch_size : (k+1) * mini_batch_size]
        mini_batch_X2R = shuffled_X2R[k * mini_batch_size : (k+1) * mini_batch_size]
        mini_batch = (mini_batch_XE, mini_batch_X1R, mini_batch_X2R)
        mini_batches.append(mini_batch)
    Lower = int(num_complete_minibatches * mini_batch_size)
    Upper = int(m - (mini_batch_size * math.floor(m/mini_batch_size)))
    if m % mini_batch_size != 0:
        mini_batch_XE = shuffled_XE[Lower : Lower + Upper, :]
        mini_batch_X1R = shuffled_X1R[Lower : Lower + Upper]
        mini_batch_X2R = shuffled_X2R[Lower : Lower + Upper]
        mini_batch = (mini_batch_XE, mini_batch_X1R, mini_batch_X2R)
        mini_batches.append(mini_batch)

    return mini_batches

MTL = MTLnet()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(MTL.parameters(), lr=LR)
loss_func = nn.MSELoss()
```

The neural network has the following structure:

```py
<bound method Module.parameters of MTLnet(
  (sharedlayer): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=64, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
  )
  (scoring_list): ModuleList(
    (0): Sequential(
      (0): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32, bias=True)
      (1): ReLU()
      (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
      (3): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=16, bias=True)
      (4): ReLU()
      (5): Dropout(p=0.5)
      (6): Linear(in_features=16, out_features=1, bias=True)
    )
    (1): Sequential(
      (0): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32, bias=True)
      (1): ReLU()
      (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
      (3): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=16, bias=True)
      (4): ReLU()
      (5): Dropout(p=0.5)
      (6): Linear(in_features=16, out_features=1, bias=True)
    )
  )
)>
```

The initial values of the weights are (yours will differ):

```py
print(MTL.state_dict()['scoring_list.0.6.weight'])
print(MTL.state_dict()['scoring_list.1.6.weight'])
```

Output:

```py
tensor([[-0.0240, -0.1798, -0.2393, -0.2149, -0.1393,  0.1718, -0.1476,  0.0346,
          0.2485, -0.0305, -0.1574,  0.1500, -0.2356, -0.0597,  0.0291,  0.0521]])
tensor([[ 0.2046, -0.1277, -0.2103, -0.1006, -0.1311,  0.1902, -0.0969, -0.0953,
          0.1340,  0.1506, -0.1222, -0.0638, -0.0661,  0.1118, -0.1009, -0.1438]])
```

The following code trains the neural network and prints the weights after every epoch. The first epoch will train the shared layer and the first element of nn.ModuleList() (i.e. task1). The second epoch will train the shared layer and the second element of the nn.ModuleList() (i.e. task2).

```py
trainTask1 = True
epoch = 2

for it in range(epoch):
    minibatches = random_mini_batches(X_train, Y1_train, Y2_train, mb_size)
    for minibatch in minibatches:
        XE, YE1, YE2  = minibatch 

        if trainTask1:
            Yhat = MTL(XE, 0)
            loss = loss_func(Yhat, YE1.view(-1,1))
        else:
            Yhat = MTL(XE, 1)
            loss = loss_func(Yhat, YE2.view(-1,1))        

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        #Shows you the weights of task 1 and they get adjusted during the 2 epoch even if no training has happened
        #print("Task 1 weights {}".format(MTL.state_dict()['scoring_list.0.6.weight']))

    #@prosti suggested to freeze the layers of the task which aren't trained
    if trainTask1:
        trainTask1 = False
        for param in MTL.scoring_list[0].parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
    else:
        trainTask1 = True
        for param in MTL.scoring_list[1].parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

    print(it)
    print(MTL.state_dict()['scoring_list.0.6.weight'])
    print(MTL.state_dict()['scoring_list.1.6.weight'])
```

Output:

```
0
tensor([[-0.0283, -0.2025, -0.2181, -0.2183, -0.1438,  0.1605, -0.1715,  0.0863,
          0.2765, -0.0153, -0.1519,  0.1704, -0.2453, -0.0539,  0.0220,  0.0739]])
tensor([[ 0.2046, -0.1277, -0.2103, -0.1006, -0.1311,  0.1902, -0.0969, -0.0953,
          0.1340,  0.1506, -0.1222, -0.0638, -0.0661,  0.1118, -0.1009, -0.1438]])
1
tensor([[-0.0311, -0.2114, -0.2162, -0.2214, -0.1463,  0.1614, -0.1800,  0.1003,
          0.2850, -0.0148, -0.1576,  0.1809, -0.2511, -0.0575,  0.0221,  0.0844]])
tensor([[ 0.2693, -0.0921, -0.2313, -0.1483, -0.0995,  0.2497, -0.1028, -0.1108,
          0.1405,  0.1997, -0.1266, -0.0725, -0.0871,  0.1472, -0.0924, -0.0994]])
```

After the first epoch the weights of task1 were adjusted but not the weights of task2 (as expected), but after the second epoch the weights of both tasks were adjusted. That shouldn't happen.

You can also see that when you print the weights during the over minibatches (just uncomment the print), they are always get adjusted for the first task even if all layers were freezed and no calculation has happened.

Is there another cache I have to clear besides `optimizer.zero_grad()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you monitor `MTL.scoring_list[0][6].weight.grad` and `MTL.scoring_list[1][6].weight.grad` during training, you'll notice that, in the first epoch, `MTL.scoring_list[1][6].weight.grad` is None, while in the second epoch, `MTL.scoring_list[0][6].weight.grad` is a zero tensor.

Looking at the source of `.step()` for various optimizers, it appears that they don't check for `.requires_grad`. They only check if `.grad` is `None`. So even if `.grad` is a zero tensor, `optimizer.step` will still do its thing. Whether this ends up affecting the frozen weights or not depends on the exact computations that the optimizer performs.

As a quick fix, you can add `param.grad = None`, after `param.requires_grad = False`, so that the optimizer ignores those parameters entirely. This seems to fix the problem. But you might still want to think about any implications it might have for the optimizer's calculations for future epochs.

Comment: You are right I have to think about further implications, but from a technical perspective, this answers my question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You could have

```
num_minibatches = input_size // mb_size
```

The trick to freeze layer is to put the computation inside:

```
with torch.no_grad():
     # do something with parameters
```

or to use

```
requires_grad(l, False)
```

Where `l` is the layer.

> Is there another cache I have to clear besides optimizer.zero_grad()

This code `optimizer.zero_grad()` should be done all the time, before `loss.backward()` but even then the gradients will be computed on `loss.backward()` and updated on `optimizer.step()`.

Comment: Hi prosti,
that didn't change anything. The weights are still adjusted. I have modified the code of my question to freeze the layers of the tasks which is currently not trained but they still get adjusted. Could you please have a look again?

Comment: You are very good, just you need to move my freez code before `loss.backward() ;        optimizer.step()` and after `optimizer.zero_grad()`

Comment: Still no difference. During the second epoch the weights of the first task get still adjusted even if calculation happens only for the second task and `for param in MTL.scoring_list[0].parameters():
    print(param.requires_grad)` returns false for all the layers of the first task.